# Google Analytics.js not working between same browsers on different OS

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, reactjs, google-analytics

I am writing a site in react and I use react-ga module to initialize google analytics.

In linux, if I check my site with Chrome Version 52.0.2743.82; it loads the analytics.js correctly.

[Developer Tools - Javascript Traffic @Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sNd0.jpg)

But in Windows, when I check my site with Chrome Version 53.0.2785.89; it does not load the analytics.js. Instead the Developer tools reports this:

[Developer Tools - Javascript Traffic @Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0hsI.jpg)

In Linux everything is working correctly (Tag assistant finds the tag, debugger shows pagesviews, etc) but in Windows it is not.

Does anybody knows what could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the ad-blocker I was using (uBlock Origin) in Chrome was blocking analytics.js from downloading. Disabling the ad-block fixed the problem.